# jQuery AnythingSlider And Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found an anything slider example, but I can't seem to get the pics to start when the page loads. It only starts when you click on the box(you can see the outlines of where the anything slider is), also I'm trying to validate some info on a form on the page. I don't have any errors with my JS, but nothing validates. Here is my JS below and here is the link to my JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jskaggs/PjR2Q/

```
$(function() {
$('#tabs').tabs();

$('#rt_depart_date').datepicker();

$('#rt_return_date').datepicker();

$('#ow_depart_date').datepicker();

$('#travel').validate({
    rules: {
     rt_departure_city: {
        required: true,        
      },
     rt_arrival_city: {
        required: true,         
     }, 
     rt_depart_date: {
        required: true,         
     },
     rt_return_date: {
        required: true,         
     },    
   }, //end rules
messages: {
     rt_departure_city: {
        required: 'Required field.',        
     },
     rt_arrival_city: {
         required: "Required field.",
     },      
     rt_depart_date: {
        required: 'Required field.',        
     },
     rt_return_date: {
        required: 'Required field.',        
     },

   }//end messages

}); // end validate

});



$(document).ready(function() {

var currentAlbum = "Airports",
albums = {
    "Airports 1": {
        "Pic 1" : "images/14.jpg",
        "Pic 2"  : "images/airport-coworking.jpg",
        "Pic 3"   : "images/airports-homepage.jpg"
    },
    "Airports 2": {
        "Pic 4"  : "images/chania-airport.jpg",
        "Pic 5"   : "images/Mumbai_Airport.jpg",
        "Pic 6" : "images/Washington.jpg"
    },

},
$slider = $('#slider'),
sliderOptions = {
    autoPlay : true,
},
icon = '&#8801;', // album icon
$album, $overlay,
showAlbum = function(slider){
    var $icon = $('<span class="icon">' + icon + '</span>');
    slider.$window
        .prepend($icon)
        .on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
            $icon.toggle(e.type === 'mouseenter');
        })
        .on('click', function(){
            $album.show();
            $overlay.show();
        });
},
setupAlbum = function(slider){
    var t = '<div class="album-list">',
    j = 0, albms = [], thumbs = [];
    $overlay = $('<div class="overlay"></div>')
        .prependTo(slider.$window)
        .on('click', function(){ $album.hide(); });
    $.each(albums, function(i, v){
        j = 0;
        albms.push(i); // save album name
        $.each(v, function(i, a){
            // only get the first image of the album for the thumb 
            if (j++ === 0) { thumbs.push(a); }
        });
    });
    j = 0;
    $.each(albums, function(i, v){
        t += '<div class="album-thumbs" data-index="' + j + '"><img src="' + thumbs[j] + '"><span>' + albms[j++] + '</span></div>';
    });
    $album = $(t + '</div>').prependTo(slider.$window);
    $album.find('.album-thumbs').on('click', function(){
        currentAlbum = albms[ $(this).attr('data-index') ];
        setupSlider(currentAlbum);
        return false;
    });
},
setupSlider = function (album) {
    var img, t = '';
    $.each(albums[album], function (i, v) {
        t += '<img data-title="' + i + '" src="' + v + '">';
    });
    $overlay.hide();
    $album.hide();
    $slider
        .html(t)
        // update AnythingSlider
        .anythingSlider();
    // go back to the first slide
    $slider.data('AnythingSlider').gotoPage(1, false, null, -1);
};
// set up AnythingSlider
sliderOptions.onInitialized = function(e, slider){
    showAlbum(slider);
    setupAlbum(slider);
};
sliderOptions.onSlideInit = function(e, slider){
    $overlay.hide();
    $album.hide();
};
sliderOptions.navigationFormatter = function(i, panel){
    return panel.attr('data-title');
};
$slider.anythingSlider(sliderOptions);
setupSlider(currentAlbum);   

});   //end doc ready
```

Appreciate some pointers.

Comment: where are the pics? add them to your sample. You can use http://placekitten.com/

Comment: I just changed the links...sorry they were saved locally on my machine. fiddle doesn't display it for some reason, but FF has no problem. http://jsfiddle.net/jskaggs/PjR2Q/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the error, and it's quite simple.

Instead of `currentAlbum = "Airports"` you should `currentAlbum = "Airports 1"`.

Found that by looking at the console, there was an javascript error there, just looked at the call stack and it was easy.

But wasn't so easy cause i had to setup the fiddle with all the scripts and external references before, which you should have done. And if you just did that you probably would find the error yourself quite easily as I did.

Here's the fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/vNa2p/

Comment: Nice catch, but do you have any pointers for the validation. The form is not suppose to submit unless you you select a departure city and date, and a return city and date.

Comment: i removed the validation part so i didn't had to add even more resources. don't remove it from your original code.